# UIDatePicker: time mode: initialize the time (gotta be simple)

Tags: iphone, nsdate, uidatepicker, ios4

All,

This seems like such a simple thing, but I cannot find* the right method to create a UIDatePicker, in time mode, and have it initialized to a specific time.  I don't want date -- just time (think alarm clock).  I have created a NSDate object:

```
NSDate * date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: (NSTimeInterval) delta];
pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];  // which should be 'now' right?
pickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;  // which creates just the clock
[pickerView setDate:date];
```

and in the first line, the interval (delta) is zero.  It displays 7:00PM.

This has gotta be so simple that I'm missing it, but I can't find the right way -- anyone?

Thank you in advance!

:bp:

*yes, I have looked, but apparently not in the correct places :(

Answer (score 0):

Take the time zone into account. You will get 0AM only if you are at UTC.

Comment: Thank you for the response!
I did set the time zone to both the default and the real time zone.  Since this is in the iPhone simulator, the location believes itself to be California.   

The *real* question, I suppose, is if I want to initialize the DatePicker time to:  7:14 AM -- how do I?  All I want to get out of it is the value after it is changed, e.g., 7:20 AM.  

Is this even the right widget to use?

Comment: to set the time [pickerView setDate:date]; is correct, you just need to set a date with the right time. To get the date that is selected just do [pickerView date] and get the time from the date.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you dkk -- I appreciate your help.  The real answer was to not use a DatePicker, but to use a PickerView (w/o the date).  That made things simpler and do-able.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
date = [[NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] dateFromComponents:[[NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:date]];
date = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:60 * 60 * 21];

pickerView.date = date;
```

The steps here with the date are

- initialise date with the current date
- get the date at midnight
- add a time interval to the date (60 seconds * 60 minutes * hour). In this case 21 = 9pm

This works for `UIDatePicker` with `datePickerMode` of `UIDatePickerModeTime` & `UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer`